Not understanding the proof of $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=\inf\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\sup\limits_{k\ge n}a_k)$
I'm currently self-studying Analysis 1 and came across a proof written below regarding the limit supremum of a sequence. The equality itself and motivation behind it is clear to me (I have proved something simmilar with set unions on my own), however I have no idea where a certain piece of the proof comes from.
The proof is written in Polish, but I'm sure I translated it accurately.

Theorem 3.39
Assumtions: $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ (extended reals)
Thesis: $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=\inf\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\sup\limits_{k\ge n}a_k)$
Proof: First, let $l=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n, ~~ p=\inf\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\sup\limits_{k\ge n}a_k)$.
Let $L\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ be such that it satisfies $L>l$. Then the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:a_n\ge L\}$ is finite, so for sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}a_k\le L$. Hence $p\le L$. We have obtained the implication $(L\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}, L>l)\Rightarrow (L\ge p)$ from which $p\le l$ folows.
If $P\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ satisfies $P>p$, then there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sup\limits_{k\ge m}a_k\le P$. Then $a_k\le P$ for all $k\ge m$ and we can easily deduce that $l\le P$. We have obtained the implication $(P\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}, P>p)\Rightarrow (P\ge l)$ from which $l\le p$ folows and finishes the proof of equality $l=p$.

My confusion
I do not understand the last two lines in both paragraphs (bolded above). Why does this follow from the implication before it and why is it so importat that this is the implication we obtained, i.e. the author never before outlined that a certain implication has been obtained, only in this proof. Can it not be the case (based on this proof) that $L\ge p > l$? Thanks in advance for any explanation of this.
Edit
I am using the definition of $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}$ that deals with the set of subsequential limits (can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior#Definition_for_sequences). In short, let E be a set which we'll call the set of subsequential limits of a sequence $a_n$. Then $a\in E$ iff there exists a subsequence of $a_n$ convergant to $a$.

I am not that happy with the proof in the book, we could have $l = \infty$ and/or (well, "or" supposing that we don't already know they're equal!) $p = \infty$ meaning that we can't take $L > l$ or $P > p$. For example if $a_n = n$. Then $\{n \in \mathbb N : a_n \ge L\}$ is infinite for each $L$.
$(1a)$ if $L > l$, then from the definition of the limit superior we have $|\sup_{k \ge n} a_k - l| \le (L - l)/2$ for $n \ge N$, say. We then obtain that $\sup_{k \ge n} a_k \le (L + l)/2 < L$ for $n \ge N$. Then $\inf_n \sup_{k \ge n} a_k$ can't possibly be more than $L$, since we have $\sup_{k \ge N} a_k \le L$. So we must have $p \le L$.
$(1b)$ if $P > p$ (it's possible that we can't actually hit $p$, we could just get arbitrarily close), then since $\inf_n \left(\sup_{k \ge n} a_k\right) = p$, there is a particular $N$ such that $p \le \sup_{k \ge N} a_k \le P$. I think the rest of what is written is clear enough.
$(2)$ you've shown that if $L > l$ then $p \le L$. We have $l + \epsilon > l$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, so $p \le l + \epsilon$ for each $\epsilon > 0$. Similarly, from $P > p$ implies $P \ge l$ you get that $p + \epsilon \ge l$ for each $\epsilon > 0$.
Aiming for a contradiction, suppose that $p \ne l$. Then either $p < l$ or $l < p$. Let's suppose the former just to see how the argument works. We have $l - p > 0$ and so we are allowed to set $\epsilon = \frac {l - p} 2$, at which point we have $p + \epsilon < l$. This contradicts that $l \le p + \epsilon$ for each $\epsilon > 0$. So we have a contradiction. You could also take, say, $\epsilon = 1/n$ to get $l \le p + 1/n$ and $p \le l + 1/n$ and take $n \to \infty$, remembering that limits preserve inequalities like this. Once you are advanced enough, I would be pretty happy just to say "and taking $\epsilon \to 0^+$", or not even spare it a mention in this case.
I would rather use the monotone convergence theorem to prove this statement. That is, if $(b_n)$ is a decreasing sequence in $\overline {\mathbb R}$ then $b_n \to \inf b_n$. Apply this with $b_n = \sup_{k \ge n} a_k$ - convince yourself this is decreasing.
Feel free to ask clarifying questions.
Edit: Using the subsequential definition of limsup instead. This is defining:
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n = \sup \{\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_k} : (n_k) \text { strictly increasing and } (a_{n_k}) \text { converges}\}$$
Strictly increasing of course means that $n_k \to \infty$ since each $n_k$ is a natural number.
$(1a)$ If $L > l$, we will now argue that $S := \{n \in \mathbb N : a_n \ge L\}$ must be finite. If it were infinite, we could take $(n_k)$ strictly increasing in $S$ such that $a_{n_k}$ converges. The limit of this subsequence will be at least $L$, since every term is at least $L$. We would then have $L \le l$, a contradiction.
So we have that $\{n \in \mathbb N : a_n \ge L\}$ is finite with some maximum element $M$. Then, whenever $(n_k)$ is strictly increasing and $a_{n_k}$ converges, we have $n_k > M$ for sufficiently large $k$. We will then have $a_{n_k} < L$ for large enough $k$, meaning that $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_k} \le L$. Since this is true of all strictly increasing $(n_k)$ such that $a_{n_k}$ converges, we get $p \le L$.
$(1b)$ suppose that $P > p$. As stated, we then have $\sup_{k \ge m} a_k \le P$ for sufficiently large $m$. So, for $k \ge m$, we have $a_k \le P$. If $(n_k)$ is a strictly increasing sequence such that $a_{n_k}$ converges, for sufficiently large $k$ we have have $n_k > m$, and hence $a_{n_k} \le P$. Then the limit of $(a_{n_k})$ must be $\le P$. Again this holds of all acceptable $(n_k)$, so we have $l \le P$.

When you write in (1a) from the definition of the limit superior... am I correct to asuume you are using the definition of limsup as a limit of the sequence of supremas? I had to look it up since it does not come up in my course neither as a definition of limsup nor its property.

@Patryk yes by limit superior I mean limsup, how is limsup defined for you?

I have it defined as  the supremum of the subsequential limits and in hindsight I should've clarified it earlier. Same for liminf, and the only property proved so far is that liminf<=limsup and that a sequence in convergant in extended R iff liminf=limsup.

@Patryk Could you write out the definition you have in the question and I'll rewrite 1a and 1b. I hope 2 was ok

Yeah, all is understandable to me, I'm just looking to be sure that I can prove theorems using only the tools given. The definition I (we) are using is on wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior#Definition_for_sequences) and starts by The limits superior and inferior can equivalently be defined using the concept of subsequential limits...

@Patryk hopefully this is better. I think the working is actually non-trivial with the subsequential definition.

It's so much clearer now, I thought I was missing something since the proof goes from p≤L to p≤l instantly. TYSM!
